# Converting an existing HTML to React using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-3

I just finished learning ReactJS and was trying to go start learning webpack. I was curious if I could turn my existing website (server-side) structure into react type website (SPA). But my only issue is that I am using a lot of vendor js and css files.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Fonts Online -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Style Sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<!-- Scripts --> 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script src="js/plugins/superfish.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/plugins/rangeslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/uou-accordions.js"></script>
<script src="js/uou-tabs.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/select2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script> 
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to make it like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Fonts Online -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div id="#root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my current webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query:
                {
                    presets:['react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { 
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                        }
                     },
                     { 
                         loader: 'postcss-loader',
                         options: {
                             ident: 'postcss',
                             plugins: () => [
                                 autoprefixer({
                                     browsers: [
                                        "> 1%",
                                        "last 2 versions"
                                     ]
                                 })
                             ]
                         }
                      }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=8000&name=images/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ]
};
```

The online tutorials kind of confuse me as a beginner in Webpack. So if someone could help me out in this particular use-case, it will help me better understand webpack in general.

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: well there is no error, but I want webpack to add these js and css file to html file

Comment: just import the files into your index file

Comment: I wanted webpack to do this for me

Comment: At the end of your index.html add link to bundle.js inside script tag